# Setting up a wireless bridge with OpenWrt

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I want to connect my printer to my local network (`10.20.1.1`) but there's no cable running to its location.

So as a solution I want to put a router next to it, connect that router to the local network via wifi and then connect the printer to said local network **via** that router.

So I don't want to create a new wireless access point or a wireless range extender.

So the router should act as a bridge / switch.

I've been able to connect the router to the wifi network, but I can't get it to act as a bridge the way I want it to. Right now the router is its own subnet (`192.168.1.1`).
So connected devices can access the local network, but not the other way around because of the entire NAT thing.

I've connected the printer to it, and with some port forwarding I'm able to access it, but it's not really working the way it should.

So does anyone know how to truly turn it into a wireless bridge?

Answer (score 0):

So you want a client bridge and not a router, so see if you can turn routing off and connect the it to your existing WLAN and then preferably bridge the wireless and wired interfaces.

All this can be done with openwrt.org but I don't know if your router is supported

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a similar thing - I wanted to be able to connect a wired device to a wireless router, which then connects to another wireless router that is attached to an outside network.  Surprisingly, the hard part came after I could get the first router to act as a client.  I accomplished this with [a few iptables rules](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html) on the router running OpenWrt Backfire 10.03.1:

```
# wl0 is the wireless client device, eth0.0 is the hardware switch
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward # should already be set
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wl0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wl0 -o eth0.0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0.0 -o wl0 -j ACCEPT
```

Now the wired device can communicate with the outside world.